# Marshaling array of Serializable containing MarshalByRefObj members

Tags: c#, marshalling, remoting, appdomain, copy-constructor

I'm running into a weird issue in the following marshaling situation. I have an object like so:

```
class CallbackWrapper : MarshalByRefObj
{
    private Func<String, bool> _callback;
    public CallbackWrapper(Func<String, bool> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public bool Execute(String input)
    {
        return _callback(input);
    }
}

[Serializable]
class MyData
{
    public CallbackWrapper Callback {get; private set;}
    public UnfriendlyType Data {get; private set;}
    public MyData(UnfriendlyType data, Func<String, bool> callback)
    {
        Data = data;
        Callback = new CallbackWrapper(callback);
    }

    public MyData(MyData other, UnfriendlyType data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Callback = other.Callback;
    }
}

class MyModule : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public MyData[] Data {get; private set;}
    public MyModule()
    {
        Data = //etc
    }
}
```

I have two appdomains, which I will refer to as Primary and ModuleDomain. I create the MyModule in ModuleDomain by calling ModuleDomain.DoCallback(MethodWhichInstantiatesTheMyModule), which creates the MyModule object and stashes it via SetData for the domain. The Primary domain then retrieves this handle, unwraps it, and stores the proxy after registering it to an ISponsor. This part works. Once this is done, I fire an event for the MyModule to indicate that new data is available (this happens in the Primary AppDomain):

```
HandleNewData(this, new NewDataAvailableEventArgs(myModuleProxy));

[Serializable]
class NewDataAvailableEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyModule Module {get; private set;}
    public NewDataAvailableEventArgs(MyModule module)
    {
        Module = module;
    }
}
```

This ends up in the following method:

```
void ProcessNewData(object sender, NewDataAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    var localData= new List<MyData>();
    var originals = e.Module.Data; // ***** This is where leases get constructed and destructed *****
    // Manually mess with the UnfriendlyType member of each element in originals (this is unrelated, but is why we have to do this copy construction in the Primary AppDomain).
    localData.AddRange(from data in originals let originalData = originals[mappingFunc(data)] select new MyData(originalData, data));
    // Do more processing, add a sponsor to each of MyData.Callback, etc.
}
```

Here is where the problem comes in. I store these MyData objects locally with associations to the MyModule. Later, I use the callbacks. The idea is that the CallbackWrapper will ensure that the callback executes in ModuleDomain, not Primary. This works great for five minutes, but after five minutes, the CallbackWrapper object is disconnected and an exception is thrown. This is odd, because I explicitly register a sponsor with each MyData. When I override the lease code for CallbackWrapper, I can see what is going on:

```
class TrackingLease : ILease
{
    private static uint LeaseIdCurrent = 0;
    private uint LeaseId;
    private ILease _baseLease;
    public TrackingLease(ILease lease)
    {
        _baseLease = lease;
        LeaseId = LeaseIdCurrent++;
        Console.WriteLine("TrackingLease {0} constructed.\n", LeaseId);
    }
    ~TrackingLease()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TrackingLease {0} destructed.\n", LeaseId);
    }
    // etc
}
```

Of course, I override CallbackWrapper's InitializeLifetimeService to wrap base.InitializeLifetimeService with this new TrackingLease. What I see is this: There is one construction and destruction ever for each CallbackWrapper, and it occurs at the marked line above. The problem is that the destruction appears to occur almost immediately; the lease is clearly getting garbage collected right off the bat (I can see the TrackingLease destructor firing on a GCFinalizer thread, and the timing is nondeterministic).

What I think should be happening is that at the marked line, I get a new MyData object marshaled by value. It should contain a reference to the CallbackWrapper in ModuleDomain. When I construct the new MyData objects, they should copy this reference. If I then attach a sponsor to the MyDataCopy.Callback reference, it should keep it from being GC'd, which should let me call it in the future. This is not what is happening, but I'm not sure what I've done to muck it up. Any insight would be very helpful.

Is there any additional information I can provide that would help to answer this question?

Comment: I think your MyData contains a reference to a Proxy CallbackWrapper, not the actual CallbackWrapper when marshalled. You can check is using `System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingService.IsTransparentProxy(originals[0].Callback)`.

Comment: This returned 'true'. It's a MarshalByRefObject - should it not be coming back as a reference? How can I affect this? The goal is to have the callback execute in ModuleDomain.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to `CallbackWrapper`:

```
public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
{
  return null;
}
```

Comment: These callbacks can be updated at runtime and as such are not suitable for being opted out of memory management. Doing this does result in this behavior not being manifested, but my understanding is that it effectively just leaks the CallbackWrapper, which is not really an option since there can be an arbitrary number of them over the lifetime of the application.